# AngularJS: refactoring helper functions out of compile() and link()

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Some directives of my program need to have a quite complex DOM manipulation and some more actions in both compile and link functions.
If I wasn't using directives, I'd split that code into functions and put them outside the compile fn.

At the moment I have:

```js
directive('myDir',...):
compile: function (element, attrs) {
   var a1,a2;
   a1 = action1() {...};
   a2 = action2() {...};

   a1(); a2();
   return { link function }
}
```

Instead, I'd rather have:

```js
directive('myDir',...):
compile: function (element, attrs) {
   a1(); a2(); // a1 and a2 declared somewhere else
   return { link function }
}
```

a1 and a2 could be declared somewhere else in the directive to keep the component reusable but, at the same time, have readable code. the definition of those functions is currently inside this compile function (not shared across directives). it is only needed there and it can be quite long.

What would be a beautiful way of organising this?

I thought about wrapping the directive in a function:

```js
(function () {
   var a1 = function(params) {};
   myapp.directive(...compile and link functions, as usual);
})();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
myapp.directive('myDir', function() {
  var a1 = function(params) {
  };
  var a2 = function(params) {
  };
  return {
    link: ...,
    compile:...
  };
});
```

Comment: nice, I hadn't considered this option. I guess it's more or less what I proposed but without need of an extra `(function() {})()`. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a service that handles the behavior of those functions.

```
yourApp.directive('yourDirective', ['SomeService', ..., function(SomeService, ...) {
  return {
    compile: function(...) {
      SomeService.action1(...);
      SomeService.action2(...);
      ...
    },
    link: ...
  }
}]);
```

Comment: I considered services too but I thought it'd be too much  overhead for a helper function, specially because I won't use it anywhere else. on the other hand, it's much better for testability. what did you have in mind when you proposed this solution?

Comment: Depending on how specific those functions are to this directive, you may end up needing to perform those actions from outside of the context of that specific directive.  One possibility is if you end up creating an A/B test and create another directive to provide similar functionality.  Plus, I think it is better to keep business logic segregated from the view logic when possible.  It really depends on your use case though, because if it is directive specific logic I would keep it in the directive as [gargc](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16812361/2355083) proposed.

Comment: I agree that if those functions make sense as a service - potentially reusable behaviour-, the good approach is wrapping them as a service which can be injected somewhere else. On the other hand, the problem I see with "abusing" services for very specific functionality is that angular does not let you define "private" services in a a module, and they all end up in the same namespace. So you have to be careful avoiding name collisions. One idea is to  use prefixes like "myDirectiveModuleMyHelperService".